# How to correctly use the GAM method for time series interpolation in R

Tags: r

I have data

```
mydata=structure(list(geom_id = c(5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 
5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 
5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 
5482620L), lon = c(77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 
77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 
77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114
), lat = c(19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 
19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 
19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754
), acqdate = c("01.05.2022", "06.05.2022", "11.05.2022", "16.05.2022", 
"21.05.2022", "26.05.2022", "31.05.2022", "05.06.2022", "10.06.2022", 
"15.06.2022", "20.06.2022", "25.06.2022", "30.06.2022", "05.07.2022", 
"10.07.2022", "15.07.2022", "20.07.2022", "25.07.2022", "30.07.2022"
), b02 = c(488L, 539L, 1653L, 16566L, 295L, 527L, 529L, 24330L, 
233L, 1452L, 8063L, 3571L, 3685L, 5543L, 7317L, 4964L, 4358L, 
8296L, 12930L), b03 = c(684L, 691L, 1653L, 13535L, 646L, 684L, 
742L, 19647L, 522L, 1426L, 7677L, 2871L, 3202L, 5503L, 7328L, 
4508L, 3637L, 7716L, 10320L), b04 = c(866L, 954L, 1811L, 11540L, 
908L, 860L, 918L, 16673L, 754L, 1437L, 7358L, 2748L, 2911L, 5517L, 
7393L, 4212L, 3293L, 7451L, 8774L), b05 = c(945L, 1064L, 1990L, 
12704L, 1096L, 1027L, 1007L, 17654L, 898L, 1660L, 7860L, 2597L, 
3135L, 5067L, 7205L, 4822L, 3716L, 8391L, 9021L), b06 = c(1092L, 
1165L, 2147L, 11628L, 1188L, 1129L, 1021L, 16135L, 1007L, 1756L, 
7380L, 2614L, 3121L, 5353L, 7346L, 4620L, 4034L, 8377L, 7877L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

I want to interpolate data in 3 steps (dates-acqdate).
For example, this is complete data, this is a multidimensional time series. I need to interpolate  in three steps (3 dates)

for this I want to use the library(for using GAM method)

```
library(mgcv)
  mgcv:gam().

gam_interp(
   formula = NULL,
   y,
   time,
   predict_times,
   se.fit = T,
   s_args = NULL,
   uncertainty type,
   verbose = F
)
```

But I'm experiencing difficulties, namely i don’t understand how to correctly use the GAM method to interpolate a time series 3 steps ahead (I understand that the formula is only for linear regression?)

here I cleared the row that need to be interpolated

```
dput()

structure(list(geom_id = c(5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 
5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 
5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 5482620L, 
5482620L), lon = c(77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 
77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 
77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114, 77.72114
), lat = c(19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 
19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 
19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754, 19.36754
), acqdate = c("01.05.2022", "", "", "", "21.05.2022", "", "", 
"", "10.06.2022", "", "", "", "30.06.2022", "", "", "", "20.07.2022", 
"", ""), b02 = c(488L, NA, NA, NA, 295L, NA, NA, NA, 233L, NA, 
NA, NA, 3685L, NA, NA, NA, 4358L, NA, NA), b03 = c(684L, NA, 
NA, NA, 646L, NA, NA, NA, 522L, NA, NA, NA, 3202L, NA, NA, NA, 
3637L, NA, NA), b04 = c(866L, NA, NA, NA, 908L, NA, NA, NA, 754L, 
NA, NA, NA, 2911L, NA, NA, NA, 3293L, NA, NA), b05 = c(945L, 
NA, NA, NA, 1096L, NA, NA, NA, 898L, NA, NA, NA, 3135L, NA, NA, 
NA, 3716L, NA, NA), b06 = c(1092L, NA, NA, NA, 1188L, NA, NA, 
NA, 1007L, NA, NA, NA, 3121L, NA, NA, NA, 4034L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

How to correctly set the condition in the formula so that the data is restored in the time series usoing GAM method (NA must be restored, that is, interpolated)?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To use `gam_interp()`, I think you need to fill the `predict_times` parameter with the standardized time like

```
seq(min(mydata$acqdate), max(mydata$acqdate), by="1 min")
```

with `y= mydata$b02, time =mydata$acqdate`